# What does vertexId mean in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I saw the rest api of flink uses **vertexid** [a lot of places](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/rest_api.html). What does it mean and how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertices mean in this case basically the subtasks of the given task. You can get them from WebUI if you click on *Task Metrics* You will be asked to select the subtask, if You click on the subtask you will basically see its name and ID. VertexId is marked in red on the picture:[image]

Comment: You should get the vertex id also via the [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/rest_api.html) by requesting the plan of a job.